# nginx gzip_static location / issue

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm setting up my nginx server to be as efficient as possible. Starting with the landing page. I decided to use the gzip_static directive and it works great, Precompresses my 14kb index.html to 3kb and when calling site.com/index.html it is served.

But the issue is when calling site.com/ nginx returns a 403 (I have it setup to return 403 all the time to prevent scanners trying to find stuff they shouldnt so this is basically a 404.)

How can I get location / to serve the precompressed index.html by default?

```
server {
    server_name mxgaming.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.mxgaming.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.mxgaming.com;
    root C:\\WebServer\\nginx\\www\\www.mxgaming.com;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    charset utf-8;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    access_log off;
    error_log  C:\\WebServer\\nginx\\logs\\www.mxgaming.com-error.log error;
    sendfile off;
    client_max_body_size 100m;
    gzip_static on;
    gzip off;
    gzip_min_length 1024;
    gzip_proxied    any;
    gzip_http_version  1.1;
    gzip_comp_level    4;
    gzip_vary          on;
    gzip_types text/xml text/javascript application/atom+xml application/javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/xml+rss application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-   manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;
    server_tokens off;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }
    location ~* /teamspeak/? {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /teamspeak.html;
    }
    location /teamspeakfull(?:/|) {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /teamspeakfull.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 60;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 60;
    }
    location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svg|svgz|mp4|ogg|woff|ogv|webm|htc)$ {
        expires 1y;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }
    location ~* \.(css|js)$ {
        expires 1M;
        access_log off;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
        try_files $uri $uri/ /assets/$1/$uri;
    }
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Again, Calling and .html, .js .css works as long as you call them directly but just / doesn't.

Comment: Could you temporarily return a different code for off limit things? Might help narrow it down. Like 410 gone or 501 not implemented. Also might help if we could see some more of your config.

Comment: ok i added the full config mainly because i made some changes.

Comment: Is there anything in the error log?